# MySql complex query retroactively

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the two tables below in MySQL:

```
cr_customer   |  cr_affiliate
---------------------------------------------
CustomerID    |  AffiliateID
AccountStatus |  CustomerID
SignUpDate    |  CreatedDate
CancelDate  
ExpiredDate
```

With these 2 tables, I need to get the following info: the average affiliates per customer and per month (month since the customer is active). So I need a result like the following:

```
Month | Average number of affiliates (for all the customers, so the total)
---------------------------------------------
 1    | 0.5    
 2    | 1    
 3    | 1.4    
 4    | 1.6
```

The month will be the diff between Cancelled or Expired Date and SignUpDate. But I need to do it "retroactively", for all the past data.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do it with an SQL statement, and not sure if I will have to bring it to a ETL process ot stored procedures.
Any help here?
Below an example on how it should work:

cr_customer

### customerID   |  SignUpDate  |  CancelDateDate  |  ExpireDate

1          |  15-01-2016   |  15-07-2016      |
2          |  07-03-2016   |  09-10-2016      |
3          |  05-07-2016   |                 |
4          |  21-01-2017   |                 |  23-02-2016

cr_affiliate

### affiliateID   |  customerID   |  CreatedDate

1          |  1         |  16-01-2016
2          |  1         |  21-05-2016
3          |  1         |  21-06-2016
4          |  2         |  10-03-2016
5          |  2         |  10-03-2016
6          |  2         |  10-03-2016
7          |  2         |  07-09-2016
8          |  3         |  06-01-2017
9          |  4         |  03-02-2017
10         |  4         |  06-02-2017
11         |  4         |  22-02-2017

I would need an intermediate table I guess to show these figures:

### customerID   |  month            |  # of affiliates

1          |  1         |  1
1          |  2         |  1
1          |  3         |  1
1          |  4         |  1
1          |  5         |  2
1          |  6         |  3
2          |  1         |  3
2          |  2         |  3
2          |  3         |  3
2          |  4         |  3
2          |  5         |  3
2          |  6         |  3
2          |  7         |  4
2          |  8         |  4
3          |  1         |  0
3          |  2         |  0
3          |  3         |  0
3          |  4         |  0
3          |  5         |  0
3          |  6         |  0
3          |  7         |  1
3          |  8         |  1
4          |  1         |  2
4          |  2         |  3

And then the final result, which is easy.

### Month       |  average affiliates per customer

1          |  1.5
2          |  1.75
3          |  1.33
4          |  1.33
5          |  1.66
6          |  2
7          |  2.5
8          |  2.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: and what have you tried yourself or are you willing to pay for consultancy?

Comment: I just added an example @GordonLinoff with Sample Data.